# Receber dados do usuário antes de prosseguir com a execução do código. ANGULAR

Tags: angular

Estou tentando atribuir um usuário em um serviço, para que eu possa usar as informações do usuário onde for preciso, apenas chamando o serviço que terá as informações do usuário. Estas informações são pegas por requisições http.

Problema é que por ser minha primeira vez mexendo com angular, estou com dificuldades com execuções assincronas, então não sei o que preciso fazer para resolver o problema. Segue código abaixo

Uma outra informação: O login é feito pelo Openid, então verifico se o usuário está logado verificando se ele tem um token de acesso pelo session Storage e com o token, faço uma requisição ao backend solicitando os dados do usuário.

O código abaixo é do serviço que recebe os dados do usuário e os disponibilizo, para que quando eu o injetar em um component, eu consiga pegar os dados do usuário que esta logado.

(Já modificado, com a sugestão dos comentários).

```
import { User } from './../../app/modules/pages/loginScreen/models/user.model';
import { Observable, } from 'rxjs';
import { LoginService } from './../../app/core/loginService/login.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GlobalEnvironment {

  user: any;

    constructor(private loginService: LoginService
  ){
    this.user = new Observable((observer) => {
      observer.next({

        //var que deve contem o perfil inicial
        //de forma modular e não fixada
        role: [""],

        name: "User",
      })
      this.loginService.login().subscribe(res => {
        observer.next(res)
      })
    });


   }

changeUser(user: User){
  this.user = new Observable((observer) => {
    observer.next(user);
  });

}

}
```

O problema é que pelo angular ser assincrono, quando eu utilizo o serviço GlobalEnvironment em um component, o objeto user que esta no serviço ainda está vazio(undefined), ele não espera o contrutor atribuir a resposta do serviço de login que traz o usuario para atribuir a variável user do serviço, quando ele atribui o component onde injeto já executou todas operações com o user undefined.

Como faço para fazer os componentes em que eu injetar esse serviço aguardarem a execução completa do serviço GlobalEnvironment, para que quando eu usar o serviço, o atributo user do serviço estejá já com os dados do usuário logado.

O código abaixo é do component Header, onde utilizo o serviço para pegar o perfil do usuário e definir os botoẽs que apareceram para ele e também utilizo para pegar o nome do usuário logado e colocar no Header com um texto de Bem vindo: nameUser;

Mas quando uso o serviço ele me retorna undefined para qualquer variavel, ele não aguarda a atribuição do user no serviço.

```
import { GlobalEnvironment } from './../../../../environments/constant/global.environment';
import { LoginService } from './../../../core/loginService/login.service';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { OAuthService } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';
import { User } from './../../../modules/pages/loginScreen/models/user.model';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  /*Var user name*/

  name: string;

  profiles: string[];

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private oauthService: OAuthService,
    private globalConst: GlobalEnvironment
  ) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.name = this.globalConst.user.name;


    // Array profiles
    this.profiles = this.globalConst.user.roles;
  }

}
```

Parte do controle de roteamento que está com problema, nessa guarda eu verifico se o usuário está logado e se seu perfil é o necessário para acessar a rota, mas como o observable tem um valor inicial, ele sempre acaba comparando com o valor inicial do observable:

```
import { GlobalEnvironment } from './../../../environments/constant/global.environment';
import { LoginService } from './../loginService/login.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { OAuthService } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';
import { authCodeFlowConfig } from 'src/app/shared/loginConfig/authConfig';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuardAdminService implements CanActivate {

   profiles: string[];

  constructor(private oauthService: OAuthService,
              private router: Router,
              private globalConst: GlobalEnvironment) {

                this.globalConst.user.subscribe(res => {

                  this.profiles = res.role;
               }) ;

               }

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> | boolean {


      if (this.oauthService.getAccessToken() != null && this.profiles.includes("ADMIN")) {

      return true;
      }

    this.router.navigate([authCodeFlowConfig.issuer]);
    return false;
  }




}
```

Comment: Há varias formas de fazer, dependendo do seu contexto. Mas já tentou após o login, recuperar os dados, gravar em um localStorage ou em um service compartilhado as informacoes do usuario? E outra, se nao tem informacoes de usuario logado ainda, acredito eu, que as rotas internas do sistema nao devem ser mostradas. Se nao é mostrado, logo, o HeaderComponent nao é carregado.

Comment: Estou tentando abordar a solução do serviço compartilhado. O controle de rota está sendo feito, ele não mostra nada se não tiver uma sessão ativa e a sessão é criada pela tela do openId, onde o usuário é redirecionado caso não esteja logado, Deu pra entender? O problema é que não sei como fazer esse serviço de forma a sempre deixar ele com a informação atualizada, estava vendo algo sobre usar um observable na variavel user do serviço GlobalEnviroments e ficar observando essa variaveis nos demais componentes. Seria algo assim?

Comment: Pode usar observable também, vai funcionar. No meu caso, após login, chamo um service que armazena as informacoes necessárias em um localStorage/sessionStorage e nas telas que preciso dessas informacoes, somente busco desse service, um método que busca da localStorage/sessionStorage. Mas as informacoes vem do método de login, ou seja, ao logar, a resposta vem os dados que preciso. Porém no seu caso utiliza o OpenId, o que pode fazer é, após resultado do OpenId, chamar outro método seu, no seu BackEnd e buscar essas informacoes.

Comment: Isso mesmo, após o openId o login ser efetuado no OpenId, o usuário é redirecionando a tela de Home onde é exibido alguns botões de acordo com o perfil dela. O perfil pego por um serviço que acessa o BackEnd, coleta as informaçoes do usuário e me devolve, assim faço armazenamento delas em serviço com um observable igual eu tinha comentado. Agora o grande problema é que no meu CanActive, quando eu pego no if eu tento validar se o usuário está logado e se o perfil dele é o necessário para acessar a rota, ele está retornando falso mesmo com o usuário tendo o perfil.

Comment: O ponto é que ele não aguarda o observable receber os dados do usuário e valida executa o if com os valores padrões que defini no observable e se eu deixar de definir um padrão incial  a validão me retorna null, por não ter perfil para comparar. Irei adicionar essas classes no post para ser possivel entender.

Comment: Entendi sim. Porém no momento em que redireciona para a tela de Home, já executa o CanActive. Ideal seria mudar a rota, após ter as informacoes do usuario, logo, terá valor a variavel e ai muda a rota, assim passando pelo CanActive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vou mostrar um código que tenho, variaveis de exemplo apenas, segue:

```
app.component.ts (Main)

userService.login(data).subscribe(userInfo => {
  this.user = userInfo;
  this.authService.setAuthorizedUser(this.user); // Salva informacoes do usuario na SessionStorage
  this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard'); // Agora que tem tudo ok, vai para a rota "Home"
}, error => { // Faca o que quiser com seu erro aqui });
```

Ai agora tem a parte do CanActivateService:

```
canActivate() {
    const authInfo = this.authService.getAuthorizedUser();
    if (authInfo && authInfo.roles && authInfo.roles.length > 0) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

No seu arquivo/módulo de rotas:

```
canActivate: [CanActivateService]
```

Ou seja, ele só vai entrar nas rotas, se tiver informacoes do usuário. Enquanto nao tem isso, ele estará sempre na rota raiz ('./'), nessa rota, vai cair no app.component.ts e ter uma verificacao se existe ou nao usuário logado.

Comment: Acho que entendi. Tentei aplicar algo com salvar na sessão e verificar o perfil pela chave da sessão, o unico problema que vejo em armazenar na sessão é ter a possibilidade do usuário ir nos storage do navegador e mudar os valores, eu tento um perfil como ADMIN e outro como OPERATOR, onde se a pessoa for operator ela tem a possibilidade de no storage mudar o nome de operator para ADMIN, assim ela teria acesso a coisas de administrador e isso vejo com um grande problema. Temos uma solução para isso? uma espécie de bloqueio de alteração, algo do tipo?

Comment: Tem sim, voce pode utilizar um service e armazenar essa info em uma variavel. Mas o ideal mesmo, é validar as roles do usuário no BackEnd, já que é lá onde voce executa os métodos/consultas, etc. Nunca confie nada no Front. Se o cara alterar e acessar uma tela que nao é pra ele acessar, o que vai bloquear ele sao as consultas no BackEnd, ou seja, vai ser apenas algo visual, sem informacoes relevantes.

Comment: meu BackEnd já faz essa validação, só queria mesmo saber se tem alguma forma de bloquear a alteração do session. Mas ok, com os perfis em sessão eu consegui solucionar o problema de navegação. Muito obrigado